# Open the dialog box on the right in flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog

I am a beginner at Flutter. How can I open a dialog page on the right side of the main window
(like Bottom Sheet)?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an end drawer instead

```
Scaffold(
  endDrawer: Drawer(...),
  // ...
)
```

and to open the end drawer you can use

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
```